# How to write Text directly in a Word Textbox using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, word-interop

I want to write some text to an existing word textbox using C#.
Actually nothing happens and I don't know why.
Maybe someone can help me?

My method:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oWordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

void SearchTextBox(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc, string name, string newContent)
{
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in oDoc.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.Name == name)
        {
            shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = newContent;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
SearchTextBox(oWordDoc, "tbTest", "Please write some Text");
```

[image: Word file]

Comment: Is it possible that the textbox is within one of the base level shapes? You may need to get a little recursive if the shapes can be nested within other shapes (just guessing, haven't worked with word like this)

Comment: This looks like an ActiveX control from VBA UserForms type of text box, not a Shape, which explains why your code is not showing any effect. Unless you have a really good reason for using this I don't recommend it, especially not for C#. A content control might be the better solution. Or perhaps a form field if the document can be protected for forms. Or draw a text box, then your code could work...

Comment: Found a workaround. Using Bookmark to write to the textbox coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

var WORD = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc   = WORD.Documents.Open(@PATH_APP);
doc.Activate();

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in WORD.ActiveDocument.Shapes)
{
    if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoTextBox)
    {
        if (shape.AlternativeText.Contains("MY_FIELD_TO_OVERWRITE_OO1"))
        {       
             shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text="MY_NEW_FIELD_VALUE";
        }

    }
}

doc.Save();
```